# openpyxl issue: autofilter causes bug on sheets with a parenthesis in the name

Tags: excel, openpyxl, autofilter

I am using openpyxl to build an Excel workbook for a set of data. It consists of many different sheets for each set of data contained in the model I am working with. Part of my code activates the Excel autofilter on each sheet with data over the range that the data populates. This is done with the following type of code:

```
ws = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
ws.autofilter.ref = 'A1:E1'
```

This has worked completely fine so far. All I want is for the sheet to have the autofilter buttons on the column headers turned on, no actual filter actions. However, I started having an issue with this. Turning on the autofilter with the `autofilter.ref` code causes a bug whenever the sheet name has a parenthesis or curly brace in it. This bug arises in that when I go to open the Excel file, Excel tells me it "found a problem with some content" and offers to repair the file, and then repairing the file makes everything work exactly as I expected it would, but it needed to be repaired first. The repair log says the following short statement:

"Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)"

Everything works fine if the autofilter is not turned on, or if the parentheses are removed from the sheet name.

Why is this behavior occurring? Is there a reason or is it just a bug? For reference, xlsxwriter behaves normally in this case, properly applying the autofilter on a sheet with a parenthesis in the name, done with the following code:

```
ws = book.get_worksheet_by_name(sheet_name)
ws.autofilter(0, 0, 0, 4)
```